# In Flutter The argument type 'List<InkWell>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I see this error The argument type 'List?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'.
I try to fix this using a different way but I am not able to fix this issue.

```
import packages here

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homepage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  final apiURL = Uri.parse(
      'api url here');
  ExerciseJson? exerciseJson;

  @override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      getExercises();
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  void getExercises() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(apiURL);
    var body = response.body;
    var decodeJson = jsonDecode(body);
    // print(body);
    // return decodeJson();
    exerciseJson = ExerciseJson.fromJson(decodeJson);
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Testing..."),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: exerciseJson != null
            ? ListView(
              // "${exerciseJson?.exercises?[index].thumbnail}"
                children: exerciseJson?.exercises?.map((e) {
                  return InkWell(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      // decoration:
                      //     BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                      child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                            child: FadeInImage(
                              image: NetworkImage(
                                  e.thumbnail),
                              placeholder: AssetImage(""),
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              height: 250,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              )
            : LinearProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I see this error The argument type 'List?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'.
I try to fix this using a different way but I am not able to fix this issue.

Comment: Just try to wrap `InkWell` with `Container`

Comment: No this is not my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replacing  `exerciseJson?.exercises?.map` with `exerciseJson!.exercises.map`,
does it solve the error. else can you share the model.

Comment: Thank you .  i replacing using children: exerciseJson!.exercises!.map((e)                                                And image: NetworkImage("${e.thumbnail}"),